# Firefox doesnot support program based calling function

Tags: firefox, anonymous-function

*on clicking any row of the following program... I am firing on function mail file click....function just having alert message that shows different file name on the basis of clicking...*

****its working properly in IE .....Firefox N other browser function doesnot call on clicking on any row.. whats problem..please help me......i am writing code for your better awareness****

```
For Each info In fsi
Response.Write("<span id=" & " 'userijd'" & " onmouseup=" & "mailfileclick('" & info.Name & "')" & ";>")

Response.Write("<td width=" & "16%" & " bgcolor=" & "#FFFFFF" & " style=" & "border-bottom-style:&nbsp;solid;&nbsp;border-bottom-width:&nbsp;1px" & " bordercolor=" & "#C0C0C0" & " nowrap" & ">")
          Response.Write("<font face=" & "Arial" & "style=" & "font-size:&nbsp;9pt" & " color=" & "#000000" & ">" & Mid(contents, InStr(contents, "Date: ") + Len("Date:"), 17) & "</font></td>")


Response.Write("</span>")
Next
```

---

this is vbscript code ... i am just calling function mailfileclick ohkkkkkkk
and ohter part this page i am difing function seebelow...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function logintk(str) {             
               alert(str);

    }
</script>
```

i thing ..now you got clear about coding.... one thine more..this code working fine with Internet Exlorer ...problem Firefox and other browser....i think problem area is...
**("")**

better u know....u r helping hand ...

Comment: fix your grammar please

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (and all other web browsers) don't run VBScript code. For cross-browser compatibility, you should always use JavaScript, not VBScript.